# Erro em trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigger

Estou fazendo um sistema que mexe com monitoramento de gados e estou com uma dúvida sobre a criação de triggers after update.

A situação é a seguinte: no meu banco existem várias tabelas que possuem chaves estrangeiras umas das outras. Dentro dessas tabelas, existem as tabelas "gado" e a tabela "tag". A tabela "gado" armazena informações sobre o gado e a tabela "tag" armazena informações sobre o dispositivo de rastreamento que utilizarei para rastrear o gado. Ambas as tabelas possuem o campo "status".

Na tabela "gado" existe um campo chamado "tag_id" que é a chave estrangeira relacionada com o campo "tag_id" da tabela "tag". Com isso, pela tabela "gado" é possível saber qual é a tag que está associada a este gado.

O que eu quero fazer é montar uma **trigger after update** para que, quando no sistema o status de algum registro da tabela "gado" for alterado para "Inativo", o status da tag associada ao gado se torne "Disponível" automaticamente e o campo "tag_id" da tabela "gado" se torne null.

Por exemplo, se eu pegar o gado com gado_id = 1 e mudar o status dele para "Inativo", eu queria que o status da tag associada a este gado tenha seu campo "status" mudado para "Disponível" automaticamente na tabela "tag" e que o campo "tag_id" desta linha na tabela "gado" fique vazia.

Eu estou usando o banco de gados postgreSQL e o programa pgadmin como gerenciador de banco de dados. Eu já criei a trigger function e a trigger associando à tabela "gado", mas quando a trigger é ativada aparece o seguinte erro:

> ERROR: query has no destination for result data. HINT : if you want to
>   discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

A questão é que eu nunca usei este comando perform e mesmo pesquisando na internet, não estou entendendo direito como se faz. Abaixo estarei postando também o código SQL que utilizei para criar a trigger e a trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.atualiza_status_tag()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
'begin

select tag_status FROM TAG where tag.tag_id = new.tag_id;

IF (NEW.gado_status = "Inativo")
THEN
UPDATE TAG
SET tag_status = "Disponivel";
UPDATE GADO
SET tag_id = null;
END IF;
end; ';


CREATE TRIGGER tratamento_tag AFTER UPDATE
ON gado FOR EACH ROW  
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE atualiza_status_tag();
```

Espero por respostas e agradeço a todos.

(EDITADO) Pessoal, consegui. O meu método de declaração da trigger não estava deixando realizar uma verificação de String. Por isso, estava dando erro na linha **IF (NEW.gado_status = "Inativo")**. Estou postando abaixo o código funcional:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.atualiza_status_tag()
RETURNS trigger
AS
$$
begin

IF NEW.gado_status = 'Inativo'
THEN
UPDATE TAG
SET tag_status = 'Disponivel'
where tag_id = old.tag_id;

UPDATE GADO
SET tag_id = null
where tag_id = old.tag_id;

END IF;
return null;
end
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql





CREATE TRIGGER tratamento_tag AFTER UPDATE
ON gado FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE atualiza_status_tag();
```

Comment: Olá, GOKU. Acredito que escrevi no texto, mas estou usando postgreSQL com o gerenciador pgadmin3

Comment: Acredito que, na linha onde está escrito UPDATE TAG
SET tag_status = "Disponivel"; eu possa acrescentar um where e retirar a linha select, mas não tenho certeza

Comment: @postgisBeginner se puder, reposte sua solução no campo de respostas, e marque como aceita, não misture a solução com a pergunta.

Comment: ou se foi a solução do GOKU SSJGod que resolveu, marque a dele como aceita, claro. E poste a sua como resposta se for diferente da dele, como referência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente aterá da seguinte forma.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.atualiza_status_tag()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
'begin

   IF NEW.gado_status = 'Inativo'
   THEN
     UPDATE TAG
     SET tag_status = 'Disponivel';
     where tag_id = old.tag_id

    UPDATE GADO
    SET tag_id = null;
    where tag_id = new.tag_id

  END IF;
end; ';


CREATE TRIGGER tratamento_tag AFTER UPDATE
ON gado FOR EACH ROW  
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE atualiza_status_tag();
```

Seu select não fazia sentido nenhum, outra coisa se isso vinhe-se a ser executado todos os dados da suas tabelas teriam sido alterado devido a falta do filtro `where tag_id = Old.tag_id`.

Comment: GOKU, obrigado por fornecer a solução, mas agora está dando outro erro. Está dando o seguinte erro: Column "Inativo" does not exists.
Ou seja, na linha do **IF (NEW.gado_status = "Inativo")**, parece que o SQL está entendendo que "Inativo" é uma coluna de tabela

Comment: GOKU, consegui! Obrigado pela ajuda. O que estava acontecendo é que eu precisava alterar o jeito de declaração da trigger. Editei meu post inicial e coloquei o código funcional.

Comment: Legal editei a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema. A questão é que com o método de declaração que eu estava usando no início, estava com problemas para declarar Strings. Por isso, estava com problemas na linha **IF NEW.gado_status = "Ativo".**

Assim, eu tente declarar diretamente o código da trigger e deu certo. Notem que eu também adicionei um **return null;** no fim, porque precisa ter um retorno.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.atualiza_status_tag()
RETURNS trigger
AS
$$
begin

IF NEW.gado_status = 'Inativo'
THEN
UPDATE TAG
SET tag_status = 'Disponivel'
where tag_id = old.tag_id;

UPDATE GADO
SET tag_id = null
where tag_id = old.tag_id;

END IF;
return null;
end
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql





CREATE TRIGGER tratamento_tag AFTER UPDATE
ON gado FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE atualiza_status_tag();
```